# What's the rule under the displaying UIAlert message "app would like to use your current location"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my app I have two tabs. The first tab just controller with some functions.
The second tab has MapView with showUserLocation property YES.
As I know in general UIAlert message "app would like to use your current location" is displayed when app is launching, but in my raw app this message has time when I do the firs tap on my second tab.

Would you clarify me how can I manage this issue?

P.S.Sorry, but I didn't find any info about.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Is it that you can start the location stuff before the alert is shown?

Comment: I mean how to do UIAlert message during the app launching instead during the second tab touch.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually better to only request location access when it's necessary. In many apps, some users might not even use the location-based features. Having it only pop up when they hit the second tab is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but UserLocation is one of the key features in m app and I want to make this UIAlert message when my app is launching. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, have your app request the user's location on the default tab. That alert only comes up the first time you request a user's location.